# How will the United States adopting permanent daylight savings affect python applications?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, dst

For applications that utilize python datetime objects with time-zones, are there any implications for changes to time-zones and daylight savings time rules (not just in the US, I'd imagine, but any time-zone legislation globally as well.)

Is TZ information that python uses part of python itself (and everybody needs to update their python install?) Or does python get TZ data from the host OS and the OS needs to be updated?

I guess the real question is, ***where in the tech stack does time-zone responsibility land?***

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects

Comment: Time zone data originates with the [IANA tzdata](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).  In Python, it will depend on which implementation you use.  If you are using the built in `zoneinfo` from Python 3.9+, it will either come from your operating system's copy of tzdata, or the `tzdata` package on PyPi.  If you're using `pytz` or `dateutil`, it will come from the data distributed with those packages.

Comment: An interesting question-- I know it was closed on SO, but I wonder if it might be a better fit for [the Software Engineering SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?  Or perhaps you can find a better fit from this [list of tech-related SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/354747)...